# How to get only page_location that does not contain specific text in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to get only data if `event_params.key` = “page_location” and its (“page_location”) value in `event_params.value.string_value` does not contain some text in bigQuery.
I have a code

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `your_project.your_dataset.your_table`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS event_param
WHERE
  event_param.key = "page_location"
  AND NOT LOWER(event_param.value.string_value) LIKE '%your_specific_text%';
```

But I think this code just remove all `event_param.value.string_value` that contains that text ... for ex, from `page_referrer` as well. But I need only `page_location`.
Any suggestions?

What I want to get data when `page_location` is not like `"%/text/%"`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, your query will check all event parameter string values, which may affect the page_referrer. You can use the following query instead.

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  event_timestamp,
  event_DATE,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
 
FROM
  `dataset_id`
WHERE
   (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') not LIKE '%your_specific_text%'
```